# how can i make footer go beyond end of page without increasing body size

Tags: html, css, footer

I want a 100px footer which however will also display beyond the end of page, when scroll is "pushed down" ie. scroll to the end of page and keep scrolling after which the browser will pull it back automatically. The concept is like setting the color on html element. I can't make it display beyond the end of body though:

```html
<footer style="position:absolute;bottom:-100px;
  left:0; width:100%;height:100px;">
<div style="width:100%; height: 300px;
  background-image:url('/img.jpg')"></div>
</footer>
```

this will increase the height of the page, and if i set overflow: hidden then i don't get the effect i want. is there any way to do that sort of thing. I want a div, because I have some JS that needs to work in there...

[image: footer]

Comment: So you just want a cool effect of the footer scrolling itself up?

Comment: Also, are you OK with using JQuery?

Comment: Say you're on mobile. You go to the bottom of the page then keep pulling up with your finger. Typically you see whitespace. I want footer background there.

Comment: I am not sure what you want is even possible. Mobile browsers use this effect to signal to the user that they have reached the end of the page. If you place content “further down” using whatever means - it will only move the point at which the effect gets applied accordingly. I think at most you can disable the effect completely - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

Comment: yeah i don't think it's possible that's why i'm asking ) it's not just for mobile though it's the same for desktop. personally I don't think there's any usability issue when the content bounces back...

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible. The best you can do is change the color that shows.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body style='margin: 0px; background-image: url("https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"); background-color: red;'>
  <main style="padding: 8px;background:white;">
<h1>Body</h1>
<p>
  body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
  <br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
</p>
  </main>
  <footer style="display:block;position: relative;height: 100px; overflow:hidden">
<div style="width:100%; height: 300px; background-color: red; background-image:url('https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico');">
</div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```